# How to create mysql table and edit (or choose) the name of some columns, in only one request

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, alter-table

I have a table "cmd-services" and I use the following SQL request to create a new table "list-poles" that contains information extracted from "cmd-services" table.
I used this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `list-poles` AS SELECT `Code P`, `Name P`,  count(`CodeP`), sum(`Qte Sortie`) FROM hospital.`cmd-services` group by `Code P` order by `Code P`;
```

the problem is that in the new table "list-poles" I get columns named "count(`Code P`)" and "sum(`Qte Sortie`)". to change names of these 2 columns I need to execute 2 other queries:

```
alter table `list-poles` change `count(`Code P`)` `nbre cmds par an` int;
alter table `list-poles` change `sum(``Qte Sortie``)` `Qte cmds par an` double;
```

My question is: How to choose the name of these 2 tables directly in the first request, when I create the table ?

Thank's for help.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `list-poles` AS
  SELECT
    `Code P`,
    `Name P`,            -- You probably should have `MIN` or `MAX` or something here
                         -- Or include `Name P` in the GROUP BY

    COUNT(`CodeP`)       AS `nbre cmds par an`,  -- AS lets you name the column
    SUM(`Qte Sortie`)    AS `Qte cmds par an`    -- AS lets you name the column
  FROM
    hospital.`cmd-services`
  GROUP BY
    `Code P`
  ORDER BY
    `Code P`
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you @MatBailie, it worked well for me. Please vote for my question. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **ALIAS** for those columns.